# HTMl 5 canvas is not working with http secured pages (https)

Tags: html, canvas

HTMl5 canvas element is not working with http secured pages (https).

Anyone tell me the right way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide a sample code? Do you get any messages in console?

Answer (score 0):

If your page is on HTTPS are using JS libraries stored in a non-secure (HTTP) website, the browser wisely will reject to execute them for security reasons.

However, if you don't provide the code we cannot prove this extent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But What code do you need for this. I will give surely

Comment: The HTML page itself, if possible. Or a link to it. Or a jsfiddle... anything goes. BTW, which browser are you using?

Comment: This page throws a lot of errors in the console (F12) of resources that couldn't be loaded. Are these resources needed for what you want to do? What is the expected result?

Comment: AAAaand, the refered libraries are stored in HTTPS with INVALID certificate (https://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.6.0.min.js)

Comment: You can try to download manually these referenced files and put them in the same directory as your page, and try again.